# Token-based edit distance in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, edit-distance

I'm familiar with python's `nltk.metrics.distance` module, which is commonly used to compute edit distance of two string.

I am interested in a function which computes such distance but not char-wise as normally but token-wise. By that I mean that you can replace/add/delete whole tokens only (instead of chars).

Example of regular edit distance and my desired tokenized version:

```
> char_dist("aa bbbb cc",
            "aa b cc")
3                              # add 'b' character three-times

> token_dist("aa bbbb cc",
             "aa b cc")
1                              # replace 'bbbb' token with 'b' token
```

Is there already some function, that can compute `token_dist` in python? I'd rather use something already implemented and tested than writing my own piece of code. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, install the following:

```
pip install editdistance
```

Then the following will give you the token-wise edit distance:

```
import editdistance
editdistance.eval(list1, list2)
```

Example:

```
import editdistance
tokens1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
tokens2 = ['a' , 'bb', 'cc']
editdistance.eval(tokens1, tokens2)
out[4]: 1
```

For more information, please refere to:

> https://github.com/aflc/editdistance

Answer (score 14):

NLTK's `edit_distance` appears to work just as well with lists as with strings:

```
nltk.edit_distance("aa bbbb cc", "aa b cc")
> 3
nltk.edit_distance("aa bbbb cc".split(), "aa b cc".split())
> 1
```

Comment: This answer explain it better. 

To put it in words - 
If you pass 2 strings to `editdistance` function, it'll return the character-level-editdistance between the strings. If you pass 2 list-of-strings, the function return token/word-level-editdistance.